# How to get command invoking g++ with parameters displayed in VSCode with C++ extension?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm using the newest VSCode with C/C++ and CMake extensions on Ubuntu 18.04. I would like to see in the `Output` terminal the exact command g++ is called with, or at least compiler flags used. I had it working once, but I forgot how to set it up and online search didn't help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using VSCode with CMake, the latter can be used to list the command invoking g++. I added:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)
```

to my `CMakeLists.txt` file and I'm getting verbose listing of build steps now, including this:

```
[build] /usr/bin/g++-8 -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/paul/st/hello/main.cpp
```